# What is $T_{A}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I have been asked to show the following statements are equivalent.

1. $T_{A}$ is invertible.
2. $x \in \mathbb Z^n $ iff $Ax \in Z^n  $
3. $|\det A| = 1$

Can anyone please tell me What is $T_{A}$  here?

Comment: It could be anything. If I had to guess based on the conditions, A is some matrix with integer coefficients and $T_A$ is the associated linear map from $\mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n$

Comment: But I think there is a problem in the question. Because 3 does not  imply 2 always.@User203940

Comment: https://math.byu.edu/~tfisher/documents/classes/2008/winter/635/Lecture6.pdf
Maybe try looking at this.
It might be $T_A$ is the induced map on the torus $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: You should ask whoever asked you to show the equivalence what $T_A$ is because they should know.

Comment: @somos Yes. I would have done so. But I can not reach them. That is why , I am asking here if $T_{A}$ is a well-known mathematical notation .  However , can you please tell me does #3 imply #2? Actually I think #3 does not always imply #2.

Comment: @sani I think we would need to know more about $A$ before we can say anything. Is $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @sani What do you mean by "3 does not imply 2 always"? I suspect that you have either misinterpreted something or are wrong

Answer (score 1):

$T_A$ is the linear transformation whose matrix relative to the standard basis is $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's are some examples which might explain your confusion in the comments.

If we interpret $T_A : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ instead, then $T_A$ invertible does not necessarily imply $\det(A) = \pm 1$. Take

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $A \in M_2(\mathbb{Z}),$ $T_A$ invertible with inverse given by $T_B$, where
$$ B= \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix},$$
but $\det(A) \neq \pm 1$. So (1) does not imply (3), and we see we need to interpret $T_A : \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n$ for your statement to make sense. Moreover, we actually get (1) doesn't imply (2) either. Notice that $A \cdot (1/2,1/2)^T = (1,1)^T \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, but $(1/2, 1/2)^T$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

To see why we need $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Z}),$ take

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(1/2) & -\sin(1/2) \\ \sin(1/2) & \cos(1/2) \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $\det(A) = 1$, but $A \cdot (1,0)^T \notin \mathbb{Z}^n$. So (3) does not imply (2).

Under all of the appropriate assumptions ($T_A: \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n$, $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$) these statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Given the context, $T_A$ is the map from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to itself defined by
$$
x \in \mathbb{Z}^n \substack{T_A \\ \longmapsto} Ax \in \mathbb{Z}^n.
$$